# FFmpeg - Filter overlay has an unconnected output

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg, android-11

I am using the library `implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.4.LTS'`.
I need to put together 3 videos, add 3 pictures and music to them. I am generating the following code:

```
-y -i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/video_20211111_141930.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/video_20211111_141946.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/video_20211111_141958.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Maramax/IMAGETEXT.png -i /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Maramax/IMAGESTICKER.png -i /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Maramax/logo.png -filter_complex [0:v:0][1:v:0][2:v:0]concat=n=3:v=1[merg0];[3]scale=1280:720[i0];[merg0][i0] overlay=0:0[merg1];[4]scale=1280:720[i1];[merg1][i1] overlay=0:0[merg2];[5]scale=195:136[i2];[merg2][i2] overlay=766:30[merg3] -c copy -threads 4 -vcodec libx264 -c:a aac -preset ultrafast -shortest -crf 20 -vsync 2 /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Maramax/finalVideo0.8238299708746938.mp4
```

And I pass it as an array of cmd commands (I also tried it with a line) to FFmpeg.executeAsync:

```
Config.enableLogCallback(new LogCallback() {
  public void apply(LogMessage message) {
    Log.e(Config.TAG, message.getText());
  }
});
FFmpeg.executeAsync(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponse(this.delegate, filepath));
```

I get this result:

```
E/mobile-ffmpeg: Filter overlay has an unconnected output
```

Video is not being collected. If I remove -filter_complex with its arguments, the problem goes away, i.e. there is an error somewhere in this command. Tried wrapping the value for -filter_complex in single and double quotes, throws an error. Removing the space before overlay didn't help either. On Android 10 and below, everything works fine. This error happens on Android 11.
This library is outdated and it is advisable to go to https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit, but if you can solve the problem on this library, the transition is undesirable, since there are many problems with ffmpeg-kit too.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** ffmpeg doesn't know that you want to use `[merg3]` as your output video.

That's why `[merg3]` is an unconnected output. It is not used for anything.

**Solution:** Select the output pad `[merg3]` with the `map` option.

Additionally you may also use the `map` option to select the audio from the first input:

`...;[merg2][i2] overlay=766:30[merg3] -map "[merg3]" -map 0:a -c copy ...`